# .Net Youtube Client Api V3 slow upload

Tags: c#, vb.net, youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I experiment some diffculties with Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.
When I initialized a transfert, the bandwith didn't exceed 120Kb/s.
When I try to make an upload directly on youtube, my bandwith go up to 1Mb/s.

I've tried to disable gzip but i didn't see any difference.

See below my code to upload a file with .net Api. For information, this code was picked up from youtube api sample.

```
        Dim youtubeService__1 = New YouTubeService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With { _
            .HttpClientInitializer = OAUth2Credential, _
            .GZipEnabled = True, _
            .ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name _
                                       })
        Dim video = New Video()
        video.Snippet = New VideoSnippet()
        video.Snippet.Title = "Default Video Title"
        video.Snippet.Description = "Default Video Description"
        video.Snippet.Tags = New String() {"tag1", "tag2"}
        video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22"
        video.Status = New VideoStatus()
        video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "private"

        Dim filePath = "D:\record\big_buck_bunny_1080p_h264.mov"

        Using fileStream = New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open)
            Dim videosInsertRequest = youtubeService__1.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*")
            videosInsertRequest.Upload()
        End Using
```

Do someone have the same problem that me ?

Comment: I have recently found the same with the PHP API. I replaced a couple of the functions in the example script but still couldn't exceed 770KB/s. In the end I used Python for ~24MB/s uploads. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326524/youtube-api-v3-upload-speeds/34381315#34381315

Comment: Finally, after 1 day to find where is the problem with no clue, I supposed the problem come from YouTube. 2 days later, I've got a good bandwith. Very Strange. I will check your python code. Thanks.