# YouTube API v3 upload speeds

Tags: php, youtube-api

I have been performing some testing with the YouTube API v3, uploading video files existing on my Apache server (VPS running CENTOS 6.7 x86_64 on Virtuozzo, 2GB RAM and a ton of CPU) using the [provided resumable upload script](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php?hl=en#upload_a_video).

Having tried all manor of things, the maximum upload speed I've been able to achieve is not more than 120KB/s.

I've been playing around with output buffers, [turning off GZipping](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/59), varying chunk sizes (from 1 to 30MB), and checked the server bandwidth speed (consistently over 250 Mb/s in the upload direction).

I struggle to believe, given how fast you can upload through the browser (I can't test this theory right now as I'm on a very slow internet connection - but this is based on past experience) that this is a limitation of YouTube, unless it's intentional throttling. I cannot find any documentation of expected speeds via the API on the YouTube docs or anywhere on the internet.

Has anyone else encountered slow uploads and is there anything that can be done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: On speedtest.net, I get 93Mbps upload speed. However, I have *never* seen an upload much faster than 3.5Mbps through the YouTube API v3, and is often slower than that (although very rarely as slow as the 120KB/s you are seeing).

I haven't done accurate timing with browser uploads, but just uploaded a 130Mb file in around 10 seconds (~13Mbps), and sure I've seen it faster than that.

My guess is that uploads are throttled through the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having done a bit more testing, I have concluded the slow speeds are caused not because of throttling at at YouTube's end but more within the core infrastructure of PHP itself. However, I did managed to increase the speed using PHP from ~120KB/s to ~770KB/s by changing Google's example approach, using `stream_get_contents` instead of `fread` ([credit to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14670761/3596962)).

However, if you still need more, I'd suggest going the Python approach. Through the API I uploaded a 2GB file in 83 seconds, which comes out at ~24MB/s. It'd be interesting to know the fundamental programming reasons behind the drastic differences in speeds if anybody knows, though well out of my realm I'd hasten to add.

Comment: Weird, I have 12 mbit uploading speed in Firefox, but only 1.5 mbit using youtube api in python