# youtube api upload file: invalid syntax on except HttpError, e

Tags: python, youtube, google-api, youtube-api, syntax-error

My python version is 3.5.1, trying to run this code https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#upload_a_video
Fixed the outdated print calls, now it gives me SyntaxError: invalid syntax error

```
def resumable_upload(insert_request):
  response = None
  error = None
  retry = 0
  while response is None:
    try:
      print ("Uploading file...")
      status, response = insert_request.next_chunk()
      if 'id' in response:
        print ("Video id '%s' was successfully uploaded." % (response['id']))
      else:
        exit("The upload failed with an unexpected response: %s" % response)

    except HttpError, e: //error here pointed at comma

      if e.resp.status in RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES:
        error = "A retriable HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status,
                                                             e.content)
      else:
        raise
    except RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS, e:
      error = "A retriable error occurred: %s" % e

    if error is not None:
      print error
      retry += 1
      if retry > MAX_RETRIES:
        exit("No longer attempting to retry.")

      max_sleep = 2 ** retry
      sleep_seconds = random.random() * max_sleep
      print ("Sleeping %f seconds and then retrying..." % (sleep_seconds)
      time.sleep(sleep_seconds)
```

I'm complete python newbie, googled that it can be because I'm missing 'try', but its there.

Trying python because of this [YouTube API v3 upload speeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326524/youtube-api-v3-upload-speeds?answertab=active#tab-top)

Can this error caused because I have newer version than library supports? https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation?authuser=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using Python 2 syntax, which doesn't work with Python 3.

Use this instead:

```
except HttpError as e:
```

Comment: one last question:     time.sleep(sleep_seconds)     gives SyntaxError: invalid syntax error pointed at first letter e, I've read that time function changed in python 3.5, what would be a new way to make program wait for x seconds?

Comment: The problem is on the preceding line.  You don't have a closing parentheses for the `print()` call.